# Steady State and Transient in Parabolic Equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

How do you distinguish steady state and transient problem from parabolic equations? I mean, how do we know the difference about "word problem" is talk about steady state or transient?

Comment: The steady state problem is the PDE with all time derivatives equal to zero.  For the steady-state heat equation, for example, the solution is the equilibrium temperature distribution in the body.

Comment: Transient solutions decay to $0$ as $t\to\infty$